# debug-vuejs-from-vs-code: unbound breakpoint when debugging vueJS app in chrome

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, vscode-debugger

Versions:

```
Visual Studio Code: Version: 1.59.1 (Universal)
vueJS: 3.0.0
Chrome: Version 94.0.4606.61 (Official Build) (x86_64)
```

I am using the javascript debugger built into VS Studio Code.  My application structure (within the IDE) is like this:

- Root (Maven parent project)

  - backend (Maven child project in Java)
  - frontend (Maven child project in vueJS)

That is, I have a Java backend that serves a vueJS frontend, and all of it is bundled together in a Tomcat web-archive (ie, war-file).  This actually works nicely, and I can debug the Java code with the Tomcat extension in VS Studio Code.

The problem is debugging the vueJS logic.  Note that my vueJS app incorporates the TypeScript plugin.  The **debug-vuejs-from-vs-code** starts nicely (under the right debug-configuration, shown below), and I can set a Browser Breakpoint that actually triggers a break in the IDE.  So the basic handshaking between VS Studio Code and Chrome is sound.  My suspicion, thus, is that the configuration -- ie, either *launch.json*, *tsconfig.json*, or some other IDE setting -- is not quite right.  Details follow.

vue.config.json:

```
module.exports = {
  // Change build paths to make them Maven compatible; see https://cli.vuejs.org/config/.
  outputDir: 'target/dist',
  assetsDir: 'static',
  publicPath: '/myapp',
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: "source-map"
  }
}
```

Here, I have enabled source code mapping for webpack-minified files in production (ie, client-side scripts running in Chrome).  Note that my app is rooted at `/myapp` in Chrome.

launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/myapp",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/frontend",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/frontend/target/dist/static/js/*.js"],
      "vueComponentPaths": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/frontend/src/**/*.vue"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///myapp/static/js/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
        "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*",
        "webpack:////*": "/*",
        "webpack://?:*/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
        "webpack:///([a-z]):/(.+)": "$1:/$2",
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here, `${workspaceFolder}` just corresponds to the root of my source-repo.  The `sourceMapPathOverrides` are presently a mess -- a combination of the default mappings and my own attempts (thus fruitless) to map the Chrome-side javascript resource paths to the source-repo paths referenced in the IDE.

ts.config.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,
    // "inlineSources": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

One programmer suggested eliminating `sourceMap` boolean and, instead, specifying `inlineSourceMap` and `inlineSources`.  I've commented out those settings, as I could not determine whether they help or not.

The vueJS-build generates outputs to `target/dist`, with this kind of directory/file layout:

```
target/dist
target/dist/favicon.ico
target/dist/index.html
target/dist/static
target/dist/static/css
target/dist/static/css/chunk-vendors.0f1ada3b.css
target/dist/static/css/app.b6011a27.css
target/dist/static/js
target/dist/static/js/app.74994c71.js.map
target/dist/static/js/chunk-vendors.377aa5d2.js
target/dist/static/js/chunk-vendors.377aa5d2.js.map
target/dist/static/js/app.74994c71.js
target/dist/static/img
target/dist/static/img/logo.82b9c7a5.png
```

To sum up, I believe the built-in javascript debugger is working fine, but that there is a configuration bug which results in Unbound Breakpoints in the vueJS app in Visual Studio Code.

Do you see the issue?

Comment: I visited menu item View>Command Palette, and then found `Debug: Diagnose Breakpoint Problems`.  If I press on the link `Why my breakpoints don't bind`, I see my breakpoint (with original source line), an explanation of why the breakpoint is not bound, and a possibly a candidate location for mapping purposes.  The hint in fact is that there is a path and/or mapping configuration issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes) for the `launch.json` attribute `sourceMapPathOverrides` is scant.  In particular, I could not locate any syntax rules for the mapping overrides.  However, per earlier comment, visiting VS Code links in the panel served by `Debug: Diagnose Breakpoint Problems` does lead to helpful explanations and hints.  I thus was able to uncover the faulty mappings, and for now, have resolved them this way:

```
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./node_modules": "${webRoot}/node_modules",
        "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*"
      }
```

My entire `launch.json` now shows:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/myapp",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/frontend",
      "pathMapping": {
        "/_karma_webpack_": "${workspaceFolder}/frontend"
      },
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/frontend/target/dist/**/*.js"],
      "vueComponentPaths": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/frontend/src/**/*.vue"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./node_modules": "${webRoot}/node_modules",
        "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

With these mappings, I was able at least to get the JS debugger to "break on load".  However, an issue relating source-line to browser-side, minified JS logic remained.  To resolve that issue, I incorporated logic [outlined here](https://ckhconsulting.com/vue-typescript-debuggers/) into `vue.config.js`:

```
const { SourceMapConsumer, SourceMapGenerator } = require('source-map');
const sourceMaps = {};

module.exports = {
  // Change build paths to make them Maven compatible; see https://cli.vuejs.org/config/.
  outputDir: 'target/dist',
  assetsDir: 'static',
  publicPath: '/myapp',
  configureWebpack() {
    return {
      devtool: 'source-map',
      plugins: [{
        apply(compiler) {
          compiler.hooks.thisCompilation.tap('Initializing Compilation', (compilation) => {
            compilation.hooks.succeedModule.tap('Module Built', (module) => {
              const { resource } = module;

              if (!resource) return;
              if (/node_modules/.test(resource)) return;
              if (!/\.vue/.test(resource)) return;
              if (!/type=template/.test(resource)) return;
              if (!module['_source'] || !module['_source']['_sourceMap']) return;

              const pathWithoutQuery = module.resource.replace(/\?.*$/, '');

              sourceMaps[pathWithoutQuery] = module['_source']['_sourceMap'];
            });

            compilation.hooks.finishModules.tapPromise('All Modules Built', async (modules) => {
              for (const module of modules) {
                const { resource } = module;

                if (!resource) continue;
                if (/node_modules/.test(resource)) continue;
                if (!/\.vue/.test(resource)) continue;
                if (!/type=script/.test(resource)) continue;
                if (!/lang=ts/.test(resource)) continue;
                if (!module['_source'] || !module['_source']['_sourceMap']) continue;

                const pathWithoutQuery = module.resource.replace(/\?.*$/, '');
                const templateSourceMap = sourceMaps[pathWithoutQuery];

                if (!templateSourceMap) continue;

                const scriptSourceMap = module['_source']['_sourceMap'];
                scriptSourceMap.sourcesContent = [...templateSourceMap.sourcesContent];
                scriptSourceMap.sources = [...templateSourceMap.sources];

                const lines = (templateSourceMap.sourcesContent[0] || '').match(/.+/g);

                let indexOfScriptTag = 0;

                for (const line of lines) {
                  ++indexOfScriptTag;
                  if (/<script/.test(line)) break;
                }

                const shiftedSourceMap = await SourceMapConsumer.with(scriptSourceMap, null, async (consumer) => {
                  const generator = new SourceMapGenerator();

                  await consumer.eachMapping((mapping) => {
                    const {
                      generatedColumn,
                      generatedLine,
                      originalColumn,
                      originalLine
                    } = mapping;

                    let name = mapping.name;
                    let source = templateSourceMap.sources[0] || null;

                    if (originalLine === null || originalColumn === null) {
                      name = null;
                      source = null;
                    }
                    else {
                      original = {
                        column: originalColumn,
                        line: originalLine + indexOfScriptTag,
                      };
                    }

                    generator.addMapping({
                      generated: {
                        column: generatedColumn,
                        line: generatedLine,
                      },
                      original,
                      source,
                      name
                    });
                  });

                  return generator.toJSON();
                });

                scriptSourceMap.mappings = shiftedSourceMap.mappings;
              }
            });
          });
        }
      }]
    };
  }
}
```

With this setup, I could launch the `pwa-chrome` debugger from VS Code and step through vueJS component logic in the IDE.

Nevertheless, I've decided that this particular combination of technologies -- ie, (i) vscode-js-debugger, (ii) vueJS 3.x, and (iii) and TypeScript plugin 4.1.x for vueJS 3.x -- simply is not the best supported environment for debugging client-side javascript through an IDE.